# Javacard, biometrics fingerprint authentication

Tags: authentication, javacard, biometrics

I would like to develope a biometrics fingerprint authentication using java card, i have found  that the javacard 2.2 provides APIs (`javacardx.biometry`) to do that, but i didn't find any informations about the Match On Card algorithm, and how to use it with `javacardx.biometry` to develop my own biometric fingerprint  authentication system.

Please orient me.

Best regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`javacardx.biometry` is only an interface and Javacard 2.2.2 is only a API specification. To which extent an actual smartcard implements all this JC API is up to the manufacturer. Similarly the `javacardx.biometry` is a convention **how** a matching should be implemented. However you will rarely find a vanilla card that actually has a fingerprint matching algorithm implemented.

I'm not very sure if you want to implement a matching algorithm or if you want to use a matching library (probably the latter?). For example, Neurotechnology has a fingerprint matching library that can be pre or postloaded into a Javacard.

The way the interface usually works:
With `BioBuilder` class you will generate an reference template. `OwnerBioTemplate` and `SharedBioTemplate` both inherit from `BioTemplate`. `OwnerBioTemplate` is the reference template that all functions, including enrolling and management. `SharedBioTemplate` only has functions for matching, validation,etc so this is a safety mechnaism that can be used if yougive access to other applets via the SharedInterfaceObject mechanism (inter-applet communication).

Comment: Thanks Paul Bastian, I didn't find any open source fingerprint matching library, so i would like to develop my own

Comment: yes this is possible. There is a huge range of standards for formats and commands that you might use. Beware that a pure Java solution is not the fastest but the easiest to do. If you are fine with the answer its common to accept it on SO. Good luck!